# commandline to send msg like java socket

Tags: sockets, command-line, telnet

We can use java socket to send msg from a client to server, is there a way to do this like using telnet or ssh ? (in linux)

Comment: what kind of message, with what protocol? your question is far too vague

Comment: @CharlesB You think it's vague, because you never met the problem, you don't understand it. Are there many network protocols you need to worry about ? Please don't say sth you don't understank!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not `telnet`, what you want is [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

Examples are on the Wikipedia page as well, therefore I save them here.

Comment: Surprisingly this is the answer that might help me with a similar doubt.  The thing is that it is hard to explain to people what is it we are trying to do.  Either we know too much or we know too little, but somewhere there is a miscommunication happening.